# About SystemProgram.assign

Tags: account, typescript

While I have a main account A and has its keypair.
Then I use createWithSeed create one account derived account x, and asign it to one program C.
Now the problem is : I want to change the account x's owner, I want to change it to another program D.

Most important : I want to do this by my own client code like this.

```
const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
      web3.SystemProgram.assign({
        accountPubkey: ada_account,
        basePubkey: signer.publicKey,
        programId: new web3.PublicKey(
          "HwFF1oi1uD14nRbDkrtrjsJqzs45WkQ9eP8YakAxG3PG"
        ),
        seed,
      })
    );

    let signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [signer]
    );
    console.log(signature);
```

Then it comes out error :

```
 logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Create: address FCJi4ZXsLdReyQB4zhLd6GqFH9w81Dm7ktXHJ7Nve3Z9 does not match derived address 5NScAVTG1uPp87Rq7WuFyYGbExW4hvhrQX9iYH2UUyCD',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x5'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an account is assigned to a program C, the only way to re-assign it is through an instruction in program C.

For example, the token program assigns accounts back to the system program when an account is closed using `account_info.assign(system_program::id())` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/7b6119895e167d4672a87cca4895c7802ca92c99/token/program/src/processor.rs#L1025

`system_instruction::assign` only works on accounts that are owned by the system program. So you need to implement an instruction in C to reassign.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the right answer about it. Ony the owner program can change the data or the account even it's system program.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it's right, so that others may find it more easily in the future